# Is the ESV rendering "My Spirit shall not abide in man forever" in Genesis 6:3 accurate?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, esv

I am reading through Genesis in the ESV for the first time and was struck by some unfamiliar wording in Genesis 6:3. It reads: "My Spirit shall not abide in man forever, for he is flesh: his days shall be 120 years."

I checked about half a dozen or so other translations, and they all use strive with, contend with, or some similar variant rather than "abide in," except the RSV which agrees with the ESV.

I think the ESV/RSV reading is interesting and wonder if anyone can tell me anything about it's accuracy or the possible reasoning behind the choice?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics—Stack Exchange!  Related, but not identical: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1261/68  Interesting question.  By the time we're done, we'll have analysed every word in Genesis 6!

Comment: @JonEricson Prophetic comment there! ... Related: [120 years until the flood, or until Adam's death, or shorter lifespans from now on?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/21005/), [What is the meaning of 'spirit' in Genesis 6?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/18864/), [Does the original Hebrew support the NLT of Genesis 6:3?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/does-the-original-hebrew-support-the-nlt-of-genesis-63), & [The Correct Meaning of Genesis 6:3 - Also Flesh or Is Flesh?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/)

Answer (score 3):

According to the footnote in the NET Bible, the word used here is יָדוֹן (yadon), which only occurs here. Apparently, it might be derived from the word "strive" (din), but then it should have been  יָדִין (yadin). The LXX translates it "remain with", which might be the real meaning of יָדוֹן (yadon). See footnote 5 at https://lumina.bible.org/bible/Genesis+6:3 and footnote 9 on page 128 in [Reading and Re-Reading Scripture at Qumran](http://books.google.com/books?id=SPgkPA4aPz0C&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128#v=onepage&q&f=false)